# Assembly Loading Error from T4Template

Tags: .net, t4

i am facing a strange problem. 
Am using a tt(text template) for code generation and added one assembly using

<#@ assembly name="$(DevEnvDir)Extensions\Microsoft\Entity Designer Database Generation Power Pack\1.0\Microsoft.Data.Entity.Design.DatabaseGenerationToolkit.dll"#>
<#@ import namespace="Microsoft.Data.Entity.Design.DatabaseGeneration" #>
<#@ import namespace="Microsoft.Data.Entity.Design.DatabaseGenerationToolkit" #>

but this particular assembly(Microsoft.Data.Entity.Design.DatabaseGenerationToolkit.dll) references another dll 'Microsoft.Data.Entity.Design, Version=10.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' which is not present because i was update the assembly to version "10.6.10617.1" and am running into problem

Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Data.Entity.Design, Version=10.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)

Is there any way to do assembly redirection in .tt templates.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately this is't possible today Biju.
The product bug logging site is here: http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio